# Is it possible to plot mirror-flipped text in R?

Tags: r

I know that there is str argument in the text function; it would be nice for me to be able to plot the the mirrored letters / strings too... Any idea?

Comment: not easy I think ... you could probably write the text out as an image, use ImageMagick to flip it, and read the image file back in ...

Comment: Most letters have corresponding reversed representations in unicode. Findings those alternative unicode characters for each letter will be a bit of a challenge, but it is probably easier than hacking a mirror image.

Comment: ... see http://twiki.org/cgi-bin/view/Blog/BlogEntry201211x1 .  It's pretty ugly though.  If you want you can go through and view the source code along with the correspondence tables (and re-implement the functionality in R ...) it's pretty ugly/unsatisfying though, making use of lots of symmetric capital letters and other *ad hoc* substitutions: ʜǫuoʜƚ ,ylǫu yƚƚɘɿq ƨ'ƚI .bɘɿoɿɿim ƨi ƚxɘƚ ƨiʜƚ ,ollɘʜ

Comment: Why don't you use [a mirror image font](http://www.ffonts.net/Street-Slab-Mirror.font) for those purposes?

Answer (score 10):

You could play with grImport, but it's rather convoluted

[image]

```
library(grImport)

cat("%!PS 
 /Times-Roman findfont 
 100 scalefont 
 setfont 
 newpath 
 0 0 moveto 
 -1 1 scale
 (hello) show", file="hello.ps")

PostScriptTrace("hello.ps", "hello.xml")
hello <- readPicture("hello.xml")
grid.newpage()
grid.picture(hello)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on the all-powerful tikzDevice package, whereby LaTeX processes the strings

```
library(tikzDevice)

tikz("mirror.tex", standAlone = TRUE, height=2,width=4)
plot(1,1, xlab="\\reflectbox{Otto and Hannah mostly won't care}")
dev.off()
```

[image]